# Android iBeacon Receiving Single Specified Signal

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, ibeacon-android

I am receiving a range of signals from onReceive using BroadcastReceiver in my iBeaconProject. What I would like to do is to only keep track of one of the beacons (which I specify) and it's distance from my phone to the beacon. Any ideas, guys? Please help me! I'm using http://www.radiusnetworks.com. I am getting a range of signals using the following onReceive function. How do I go about doing it? Thanks all in advance!

```
BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int countBea = 0; 
        if (intent.getAction().equals(intentname) && intent.getExtras() != null && intent.getExtras().containsKey(intentname)) {
            Collection<IBeacon> beaconsCol = (Collection<IBeacon>)intent.getExtras().getSerializable(intentname);

            for (IBeacon bea : beaconsCol) {

                    Log.d("beac receive!","receive! "+bea.getProximityUuid()+" "+bea.getMajor()+" "+bea.getMinor()+" "+bea.getAccuracy()+" "+bea.getProximity()+" "+bea.getRssi()+" "+bea.getTxPower());
                    countBea++;
                     if(((mainActivity)getActivity()).UUIDValue.equalsIgnoreCase(bea.getProximityUuid())
                            && ((mainActivity)getActivity()).MajorValue == bea.getMajor() 
                            && ((mainActivity)getActivity()).MinorValue == bea.getMinor()) {
                        update(bea.getProximityUuid(), +bea.getMajor(), bea.getMinor(), bea.getAccuracy());

                    } else if (((mainActivity)getActivity()).UUIDValue.equalsIgnoreCase(bea.getProximityUuid())
                            && (((mainActivity)getActivity()).MajorValue == 0 ||
                             ((mainActivity)getActivity()).MinorValue == 0)) {
                        updateNILMajorMinor();
                    } else {
                        updateMultipleBeaconsDetected();
                    }

            }
            System.out.println("COUNTBEAC " + countBea);

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Good to see the for-each loop.

Inside it, you can identify the beacon that you want to keep track of,

```
for (IBeacon bea : beaconsCol) {
    //in the following if, identify the specified beacon
    // this will remain the same for every refresh
    if(bea.getProximityUuid().equals("match it here") && bea.getMajor()==major 
        && bea.getMinor()==minor){
    //now display that beacon's proximity and accuracy
    //the same code will update a textview or notification every time

    // here you will have 1 beacon at a time, can add that to a global list
    }
}
```

Can you give a precise idea for the implementation?

does your code enter onReceive periodically?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! I did try adding the if condition, but it keeps refreshing then receiving another batch of signals, then it doesn't keep track of that particular one that I specified.

Comment: hey..it will if you just match it with one, the beacon that you want to identify :)  can you check the details of the beacon that you want to identify.. major, minor, uuid

Comment: yes i did, but then my code checks for extra beacons detected, then it will display that multiple beacons are detected.

Comment: i am using fragments, so the onReceive is at the fragment interface cause the beacons signal received will be shared between different fragments.

Comment: you can use a global variable(or list for more beacons) then, which will be shared between fragments but will have data of only the beacon that you want

Comment: what do you want to do after the multiple beacons are detected?

Comment: worked a lot with BLE, iBeacons and the same Radius Networks library too..the whole thing is quite tricky and also varies from device to device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54650/discussion-between-winona-and-user2450263).

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything mention using the Radius Networks SDK by listening for broadcasts. Instead they ask that you implement certain interfaces and register them with an `IBeaconManager`.

You may find their [code samples](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html) useful. That page contains the following snippet, which you may recognize as equivalent to the code in your question.

```
public class RangingActivity extends Activity implements IBeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier {

    private static final String TAG = RangingActivity.class.getName();
    private IBeaconManager iBeaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        iBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        iBeaconManager.unBind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
        iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);

        try {
            // edit this to match the UUID of your beacon
            // or leave null to detect everything
            String uuid = null;

            Region region = new Region("myRangingUniqueId", uuid, null, null);
            iBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "problem while starting ranging", e);
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
        if (!iBeacons.isEmpty()) {
            double accuracy = iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();
            Log.i(TAG, "The first iBeacon I see is about " + accuracy + " meters away.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try this code in a moment. Cause if I use the code you've provided, I need to change a whole lot of codes though. Thanks for your help!